# Ehresmann's fibration theorem for CW or simplicial complexes

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, fibration, cw-complexes

Is there an analogue of Ehresmann fibration theorem for (finite) CW complexes ?

Note is not true that an open surjective (necessary proper) cellular map of finite CW or simplicial complexes is necessarily a Serre fibration: ramified coverings of surfaces are counterexamples, as pointed out in comments.

Relevant questions are:
[Ehresmann fibration theorem for manifolds with boundary](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201670/ehresmann-fibration-theorem-for-manifolds-with-boundary),
and [Ehresmann's fibration theorem in the C1 class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184313/ehresmanns-fibration-theorem-in-the-c1-class), and [Simplicial approximation of a fibration](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270433/simplicial-approximation-of-a-fibration), and [Which maps of simplicial sets geometrically realize to fibrations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320562/which-maps-of-simplicial-sets-geometrically-realize-to-fibrations).

Comment: A ramified cover between surfaces is open, and it is not a Serre fibration right?

Comment: I'm probably missing something but why say $z^2:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is not a Serre fibration ? It does have the path lifting property, right, though ? By the way, I forgot to say "surjective" and now I added it.

Comment: Its fibres do not have constant (weak) homotopy type.

Comment: sorry, of course... i'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not quite clear what you're looking for, but one possible thing to say is that [being a Serre fibration is a local condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre+fibration#LocalRecognition). Just as Ehresmann's theorem gives an infinitesimal condition which implies being a Serre fibration for manifolds, this principle gives you a local condition. Indeed, I suppose Ehresmann's theorem follows from this fact along with the implicit function theorem.

Also, regarding the formulation of the question, note that [every Serre fibration bretween CW complexes is a Hurewicz fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre+fibration#RelationToHurewiczFibrations).